# How to union some records in a pandas data frame that has intersection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a data frame with two columns. Each row contain start and end of a ranges and data frame is sorted.

I want to union every ranges that have intersection till there are not any pair of ranges that have intersection.

my solution is using for loop and iterate over all rows and union them but it is very slow. Can anyone present a faster way for this?

**Example**

Input:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 9 |
| 11 | 20 |
| 12 | 21 |

Output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 7 | 9 |
| 11 | 21 |

for creating data frame, use below code:

```py
import pandas as pd
a = [1, 2, 7, 11, 12]
b = [5, 4, 9, 20, 21]

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": a, "B": b})
```

Comment: I don't see how you can do better than O(n), since you must visit every input. Curious how you get as good as O(n)?  if all of the inputs are disjoint, a naive approach would be O(n^2)

Comment: When your data is sorted, loop on your dataframe from first to end. For each row if this row has intersection with the next row, union to ranges and then drop the first row. At the end of loop you have separate ranges

Comment: I see.  Not counting the sort, just check each range against the last disjoint range, knowing the current range can't overlap with any prior to the last one. Anyway, my initial point stands, which is there's no getting around visiting every row.  O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a new solution that is faster than for loop in large data frames. suppose name of data frame is df.

```py
df["merger"] = df.A.gt(df.B.shift(1)).astype("Int8").cumsum()
df = df.groupby(by=["merger"]).agg({"A": "min", "B": "max"}).reset_index(drop=True)
```